# I keep getting errors with an "if var.startswith" statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so that I can input someone into console and have it set a variable to it, and every time with the if statement it gives the error

```
File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
    if meInput.startswith("%send"):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Here's the code:

```
if input.startswith("%send"):
  myinput = input.split(" ", 2)[2]
  channel = client.get_channel(12324234183172)
```

I've tried putting it into a variable such as `variable = input` then changing the if statement to match the variable, but it does the same thing.

Comment: `input` is a built-in function in python. Use another variable name.

Comment: To get a line of input, use `var = input()`, not `var = input`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. If something is not relevant to your question, it should not be mentioned unless asked for (this is fairly rare, but sometimes someone will be confused as to *why* you want to do something, and the answer could help clear up a misconception). Do not talk about your level of experience; that is a distraction and it *does not change what the correct answer to the question is*.

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure you can show code that causes the exact error you describe. I reformatted your error like code to make it more readable; now I see that the code mentioned in your error uses a different variable name from the code you show. This makes it harder to understand the problem.

Comment: Finally, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to develop the skill of *reading* and *understanding* error messages. If you don't know a word, try to look it up - an ordinary English dictionary is usually good enough, especially an online one.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully!  It is telling you that `input` is not a string, but a function — a function that would return a string if you called it, but you didn’t.  Try this instead:

```
if input().startswith("%send"):
```

Note the parentheses.  That is how you call a function in Python, and in most other languages.